# Facing Exception in spring security filterchain-If this endpoint is Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-filter

I am working on one spring boot personal project where i am facing exception in spring security filterchain class.i have tried various solution ,but unfortunately nothing didnt work .

```
SECURITY CONFIG

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    
    
    //INMemory userDetails DB  ,PasswordEncoder is a interface ,BCryptPasswordEncoder is one of the implementation
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager detailsManager(PasswordEncoder p) {
        UserDetails user=User.withUsername("springer1")
                            .password(p.encode("secret"))
                            .roles("admin")
                            .build();
        UserDetails admin=User.withUsername("springer2")
                              .password(p.encode("secret"))
                              .roles("user")
                              .build();;
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user,admin);
    }
    
    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    

    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                     // If you are only creating a service that is used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.
                    .authorizeHttpRequests( (authorizeHttpRequests)->
                        authorizeHttpRequests
                            .requestMatchers("/users").hasRole("admin") 
                            .requestMatchers("/users","/users/**").hasAnyRole("admin","user")
                            .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("admin")
                            .requestMatchers("/","/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/").permitAll() );
                    
             
            return http.build();
                    
    }

}
```

```
POM.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>userApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>userApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
              <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
              <version>2.2.0</version>
         </dependency>
         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

THE EXCEPTION :

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/practise/userApp/Security/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: **Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).**

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

I am new to the springboot ,can anyone help me understand, what should i need to change inorder to avoid this exception.where did i go wrong?

I tried upgrading the spring security dependency to 6.1.1 to 6.1.2 as per the suggestion given in stackoverflow. but it didnt work and also I am not using any extra servlet in my project.

Comment: Who not just do as the exception tells you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have the exact solution but when I changed Spring boot version to 3.1.1 then it is working

Answer (score 0):

Do not just use "String"  use "MvcRequestMatcher" class or "AntPathRequestMatcher" class

Here is example on your code

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            // If you are only creating a service that is used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection.
            .authorizeHttpRequests( (authorizeHttpRequests)->
                    authorizeHttpRequests
                            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users")).hasRole("admin")
                            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users","/users/**")).hasAnyRole("admin","user")
                            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/**")).hasRole("admin")
                            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/"),new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll());

    return http.build();

}
```

for more detail  look [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html)